# Accessing Methods in Declaration vs Implementation

Tags: c++, class, methods, declaration, implementation

I'm having difficulty interpreting some of my results, which I would expect to behave the same but are not.

I am trying to write a method that returns a function pointer **getPtrFn**

I have a **main.c** file reading

```
#include <iostream>
#include "test.hpp"

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){

     Test test;

     void (*fPtr)(void) = test.getPtrFn();
     return 0;
}
```

A **test.hpp** file that reads

```
#ifndef _test_h
#define _test_h

class Test {
    private:
        void (*ptrFn)(void);

    public:
        Test(){};
        void (*getPtrFn(void))(void){
           return ptrFn;
        };

        ~Test();

};

#endif
```

And a **test.cpp** file that reads

```
#include "test.hpp"
Test::~Test(){}
```

This runs fine. However, when I move the implementation for ***getPtrFn(void)** to the implementation file (revised files shown below),

**test.hpp**:

```
#ifndef _test_h
#define _test_h

class Test {
    private:
        void (*ptrFn)(void);

    public:
        Test(){};
        void (*getPtrFn(void))(void);
        ~Test();

};

#endif
```

**test.cpp**:

```
#include "test.hpp"

void (Test::*getPtrFn)(void){
    return ptrFn;
};

Test::~Test(){}
```

I get the compile error

```
test.cpp:16:9: error: use of undeclared identifier 'ptrFn'
```

My understanding of the language syntax is that they would be treated the same. So what gives?

-Jeff

Comment: `typedef`ing the function-pointer type would really help so that you don't have to deal with horrible looking stuff like `void (*getPtrFn(void))(void)` and also makes it easier to get the syntax right.

Comment: You can choose to define member functions in the source file, but you have to at least declare them in the header file!

Comment: You're probably right. Though I prefer to do everything the hard way at least once so I understand what's going on.

Answer (score 1):

You need

```
void(*Test::getPtrFn(void))(void)
{
    return ptrFn;
}
```

instead of `void (Test::*getPtrFn)(void){...}`. `void (Test::*getPtrFn)(void)` is the declaration of `getPtrFn` as a pointer-to-Test-member-function taking no parameters (`void`) and returning `void`, so after you put the braces `{ ... }` you get a compile-time error (its like trying to declare `int i{/*some statemets*/}`).

Also, and don't forget to keep the declaration

```
void(*getPtrFn(void))(void);
```

in your header (right now it seems you don't have it, did you cut/pasted it?).
Quite a horrible thing to look at... So really, use a type alias, it makes your code much cleaner.

```
using PTRFN = void(*)(void); // or typedef void(*PTRFN)(void);

class Test {
    private:
        PTRFN ptrFn;

    public:
        PTRFN getPtrFn(void);
        Test(){};
        ~Test(){};
};

PTRFN Test::getPtrFn(void) // clear an concise
{
    return ptrFn;
}
```

In case you really really want to be able do decipher every kind of pointer declaration you can think of, try looking at the [clockwise/spiral rule](http://c-faq.com/decl/spiral.anderson.html), I found it extremely useful, clear and easy to understand. Then test your knowledge at [cdecl.org](http://www.cdecl.org/).

Comment: Yes. I did copy and Paste. The function declaration (where I implemented in the CPP file) was inadvertently not included. Though it was in the source.